# What linkage do constexpr functions have by default?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Do `constexpr` functions have internal linkage by default or external?
Take for example the following function:

```
constexpr int foo() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> A `constexpr` specifier used in a function or static member variable (since C++17) declaration implies `inline`.

[from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Comment: Being inline is a separate thing (inline functions have external linkage by default, just like any other free function, but they can have internal linkage as well (e.g. if declared static))